# complex sentence-structure

Tags: sentence-structure

'Those look less, like a new, self-sacrificing focus on institutional security, than plain bad decision-making.'

It is very difficult for me to understand. I get the part of 'Those look less than plain bad decision-making.' but have no idea of the part of 'like a new, self-sacrificing focus on institutional security.' What is the latter part describing in the whole sentence?

Comment: Where you found it?

Comment: Does it matter? The Economist.

Comment: (This is National security not institutional security)—I think

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have. It's from the article about criticizing the economic policy of China weeks ago. I joined a study meeting for English, which shared the article with participated member.

Comment: I don't remember the exact sentence word by word. I remember it from Twitter of The Economist. I have tried digging Twitter for nothing.

Comment: I got it from old correspondence with one of members:  The feeble response of China's policymakers to tumbling growth and inflation is the latest in a series of failures. These look less like a new, self-sacrificing focus on national security, than plain bad decision-making.

Comment: What is 'overally'?

Comment: To me, the sentence only implies of the ineffectiveness of the decision-making, that's all.

Comment: The Economist is known for bad writing. This is an unclear, bad sentence, and it has incorrect comma placement.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: It's also not really a question if you paraphrase a quote you are unsure about, because many new mistakes can creep in and there is no focus.

Comment: You misparsed it and/or there is a punctuation **error**. 'Those look less like a new, self-sacrificing focus on institutional security, than plain bad decision-making.' It works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious issue is the punctuation. I would omit the first and last commas:

> Those look less like a new, self-sacrificing focus on institutional security than plain bad decision-making.

Saying something is *less* (or more) like one thing *than* another is a very common construction, but the whole thing should flow as a single statement. Only one comma is needed to separate the two listed adjectives.

The writer is suggesting that "those" (whatever they are) are evidence of "plain bad decision making", but perhaps are being passed off as a deliberate strategy "a new, self-sacrificing focus on institutional security".

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it is clear to me.